Breezing Forms - how to include Summarize type of field in custom emails?
Pretty sure this is impossible, but maybe not.
I'm using Summarize type of field with totalCost name. It's calculated with custom value based on lots of fields summed up with JS.
I tried to use {totalCost:label} and {totalCost:value}, but that resulted in empty values. There doesn't seem to be any way to copy it to a hidden input on the last page either. Any other ideas?

It wasn't that hard to copy it to the hidden input after all. The workaround was to:

create hidden input with name e.g. totalCostHidden
add this code to custom value calculation of totalCost, after everything is calculated:

document.getElementsByName('ff_nm_totalCostHidden[]')[0].value = value

Then {totalCostHidden:label} and {totalCostHidden:value} can be used in mails.

Another option would have been to use a "read more" field I believe.

I don't see a field of that type

Whoops sorry I meant a read only field.  It's a text field but it's not editible, you could put your calculation in there and the user would be able to see it (depends if it's helpful or not).  I can't remember, you might need to tick a box to make it read only.  We did this to show people quotes before they submitted.  That way the business owner didn't get any quotes from people who were nowhere near his target price.
